# Upload image and and textfields to server using json formatted POST request

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, file-upload

This question may have been answered many times, but I can't seem to put it together in the right way. I need to upload an image taken by the iPhone camera and in addition I have to upload a number of other textfields. I have a JSON formatted POST request which works without problems when I just upload the textfields, i.e. without an image.
I have tried to base64 encode the image to a NSString and appending this to the JSON request, but seems like it doesn't work.
As I understand when reading a ton of Q/A this can be achieved in 2 ways: either JSON with base 64 encoding or HTML POST and a lot of boundary informations which I'm not familiar with.
Does anyone have a simple code snippet or something showing how to do this.
For the moment my code looks like this:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_selectedImage, 0.6);

NSString * base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"Base64-encoded string is %@", base64String);

jsonInputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myUrl?token=%@&project_id=%i&name=%@&amount=%0.2f&type_id=%i&currency_id=%i&payment_type_id=%i&file=%@&debug=true", _sharedDataManager.token, _projectId, encodedProjectName, floatTwoDecimalDigits, _annexTypeId, _currencyId, _paymentTypeId, base64String];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:jsonInputString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"YOUR_BOUNDARY_STRING";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:[jsonInputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {}
```

Comment: A POST normally doesn't have a bunch of query parameters in the URL. All of that data should be part of the POST message.

Comment: How can it be it works without the image then. The exact same request just without the last parameter?